# Create temp File object in jimfs?

Tags: java, file, path, filesystems, jimfs

I would like to get `File` object from jimfs - in order to use it with a 3rd party library.

```
private FileSystem fs = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.unix());                          
Path path = Files.createTempFile(
                                Files.createDirectories(fs.getPath("tmp")),
                                "myTempFile",
                                ".mp3");
```

When I call `toFile()` on Path I get `Operation Not Supported`

How I can obtain `File` from `Path` with jimfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible since `File` can be created only for default filesystem...